# Why does a 64bit version of linux mint need both i386 and amd64 versions of a package?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I just checked linux mint's 17.3 [manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxmint/mint-dev-tools/master/usr/share/mint-dev-tools/manifests/mint-17.3-cinnamon/filesystem.manifest) and lots of its packages includes both architectures. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the packages which are installed for both architectures are libraries or support packages (*e.g.* the GTK+ engines). The `amd64` libraries and support packages are necessary for the rest of the system to work. The `i386` libraries are installed so that older or 32-bit-only software can be easily installed; examples include Skype and 32-bit Wine (to run 32-bit Windows applications or games, which is still a common use-case if you're running Windows programs).

Comment: I'm mainly talking about packages like bluez-alsa that have both architectures. I checked ubuntu trusty's 64bit  manifest also, it only has amd64 and not i386 packages.

Comment: `bluez-alsa` and so on are part of the "support packages" in my answer. There's a possibility `bluez-alsa:i386` would be needed for 32-bit Skype with a Bluetooth headset. This is just speculation but perhaps the Mint developers decided it was easier to just install all that and provide out-of-the-box installation support for 32-bit binaries (whereas Ubuntu in the Trusty time-frame would perhaps rely more on its application store).